# onbeforeunload не выводит текст

Tags: javascript

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Не желаете посетить наш сайт?";
}
```

Выводит стандартный только.

Answer (score 2):

Все идет к тому, что это невозможно сделать.

Раньше браузеры выводили возвращаемый текст, в качестве текста popup, а также была возможность показывать блокирующие окна: alert, confirm, prompt

Но с [мая 2011 в HTML5 спецификацию](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#user-prompts) было добавлено, что вызовы блокирующих окон могут быть проигнорированы браузером в событии [*onbeforeunload*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

Кроме того, большинство браузеров перестало обращать внимание на возвращаемое значение и показывает стандартный текст.

Из проверенных браузеров работает в IE и EDGE, не работает в FireFox, Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

Функция return не выводит текст на экран. Она возвращает в данной ситуации строку. Для вывода текста на экран Вам надо поместить его в DOM. Как пример:

`document.querySelector('body').innerHTML='не желаете ли посетить?'`

Comment: мне необходимо вывести этот текст именно в окошке этом

Comment: alert("ваш текст");

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko, обрати внимание на _функцию_ - это обработчик события. И раньше такой подход действительно работал.