# автоматическая форма при закрытии страницы - сделать скрипт

Tags: javascript

Поставил метрику-вебвизор на свой сайт, увидел, как и сколько его посещают, удивился отсутствию писем/звонков,
и хочу сделать так, чтобы при уходе посетителя с сайта (закрытии окна) у него появлялась форма с текстом типа

"**Если Вы не нашли на нашем сайте ответа на свой вопрос,
задайте его прямо здесь:**"
< окошко для ввода текста посетителем >
**и Вам обязательно ответят**
< ввести адрес своей почты >

При нажатии кнопки "отправить" на этой форме текст, набранный в форме должен автоматически отсылаться на мою почту.

Поскольку я других языков, кроме НТML, не знаю и изучать не планирую (моя работа состоит не в сайтостроении), хотелось бы, чтобы этот прибамбас был в виде скрипта, который я просто вставлю на HTML-страницы своего сайта.
Буду благодарен за готовое решение, или ссылку,  где это сделано, 
а если нужна оплата за создание такого скрипта, сообщите Вашу цену.

Comment: такое сделать невозможно, при закрытии страницы, максимум можно показать стандартный для браузера вопрос, что-то вроде - не хотите ли остаться

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [onbeforeunload не выводит текст](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/566235/onbeforeunload-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82)

Comment: Если ничего кроме html изучать не хочется, то можно пользоваться конструкторами, например  [таким](https://getsale.io/)