# Не работает правильно onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript

Eсть простая проверка - при запуске страницы она работает, при закрытии - нет.
Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
function ExitFromPage () {
    confirm('asas');
    return false;
}
window.onbeforeunload = ExitFromPage();
```

Comment: и onunload пробовал то же самое

Comment: обрати внимание на [этот ответ про beforeunload](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/566235/onbeforeunload-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82/566264#566264)

Answer (score 1):

Вам не нужны скобки в этой строке:

```
window.onbeforeunload = ExitFromPage;
```

`()` означают, что функция вызовется сразу, как только интерпретатор дойдет до  `ExitFromPage()` - поэтому она и срабатывала при запуске страницы.

Comment: убрал скобки не работает вообще, но вроде простая вещь не могу понять в чем ошибка

Comment: проблема в том, что функция не срабатывает при закрытии страницы или в том, что она не выводит Ваш текст? если первое, то вот [пример](http://jsbin.com/tojunawagi/edit?js,output) - все работает

Comment: очень странно но вот я там добавляю простой алерт и он работает а вот закрытие страницы нет, на самой странице вобще не работает ни текста ничего, просто закрывается страница без всяких оповещений и все

Comment: в каком браузере Вы работаете?

Comment: во всех популярных проверял